# Interpolating RGB values for holes in pictures

Tags: image, algorithm

We are doing an image processing project entitled "Face Replacement System" and we are referring to http://thesai.org/Downloads/Volume1No6/Paper_22_A_Face_Replacement_System_Based_on_Face_Pose_Estimation.pdf.

We implemented "image warping", in which source image (face) (which is to replace the target image) is shifted, rotated and scaled to match the pose of the target image (face). The result obtained after image warping has holes i.e. not all the pixels of target image are mapped to the source image. The paper does not mention any solution.

We tried a simple solution: to take average of the pixels from 8 connected neighbors for each hole. We tried other algorithms too. But the results are poor.

What is the best algorithm to implement in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using affine transformations ("shifted, rotated and scaled"), so it is possible to calc back transform, and make "reverse mapping" - **for each destination pixel find corresponding source pixel**. So the appearance of the holes is entirely eliminated.

Edit: Bilinear interpolation for comment discussion

```
foreach pixel in newimage do
   (px, py) = Transform(pixel.x, pixel.y) //float
    x = Floor(px), y = Floor(py)  //integer base coordinates in old image, rounded to -Infinity
    tx = px - x, ty = py - y   //float parametric coordinates in old image cell
    Coeff00 = (1 - tx) * (1 - ty)
    Coeff01 = tx * (1 - ty) 
    Coeff10 = (1 - tx) * ty
    Coeff11 = tx * ty
    NewRedValue = OldRedValue[x, y] * Coeff00 + 
                  OldRedValue[x + 1, y] * Coeff01 + 
                  OldRedValue[x, y + 1] * Coeff10 + 
                  OldRedValue[x + 1, y + 1] * Coeff11
    the same for blue, green
```

Comment: I used reverse mapping, but the result is poor. I am now trying to use reverse mapping (but with interpolation i.e. not one-to-one mapping). I am trying to implement cubic interpolation for this. It provides weights for intensity based upon the distance of the neighbor from the mapped pixel. However, I am also getting negative values for R, G, B after interpolation. I do not know how to correct it.

Comment: Are your scaling coefficients too high or low? Usually it is enough to perform simple bilinear interpolation for satisfactory results.

Comment: weight(x) = x^3 - 2*x^2 +1 (0<=x<1) and weight(x) = -x^3 +5x^2 -8x +4 (x being positive, and x is the distance between pixel which is to be estimated from a neighbor). I got it from a tutorial. Now I will try bi-linear interpolation. How many neighboring pixels should I consider, and what weight should I assign to them?

Comment: You should consider 4 neighbouring pixels. Weights depends on coordinates of the point in the square.

Comment: @Robik Added bilinear in the answer. And I doubt about applicability of your weight(x) formulae

Comment: Weight(x) did not work. I implemented bi-linear interpolation.(by assigning nearby pixels with greater weights). The result is still poor. May be it is because I made my own formula for the weight. What is the popular formula for weight? Plus, I am interpolating r,g,b individually. ImageJ has something called getPixel() and putPixel() to operate on a pixel. It also has in-built interpolation mechanism, should I switch to ImageJ instead? I haven't used it before.

Comment: Thank you for the pseudocode. Are 4 neighboring pixels enough? Is it better than doing with 8 pixels? If so why? Anyway, I will implement the pseudocode you provided and then, come with the results.

Comment: 4 pixels are enough for bilinear interpolation. More pixels are needed for more complex interpolation (16 for bicubic, for example). Notice, the bilinear never provides weird results, as bicubic sometimes could .

Comment: I implemented the algorithm, the result is still unsatisfactory. It is not bad but it has short, faint diagonal lines in many places.

Comment: Could you provides some images (small fragments of source and result images)? Diagonals appear when pixel intencity varies very sharply, and scaling factor is high

Comment: Previously, I had reverse mapped only the holes, now I mapped the whole picture. It is giving realistic results. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the median filter that you are describing (the 8 connected neighbors thing) would probably be best. You could do more specific filtering but the specialization is probably not needed...especially if the "holes" aren't very big.

Comment: It is not giving good results, so I need a new idea. Please read my answer above.